# Mplayer support SMB

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, smb, mplayer

How could I transplantation Mplayer to iOS?  and make it support SMB?

I build the ffmpeg,but the other  thing is  I do not  know  how to make this support smb.

what I  want  is  to  developer  a  player  support smb   on  iOS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typed in *ffmpeg smb support* into google. And it came back with this [part of the official documentation that you obviously should read](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#libsmbclient) about FFmpeg's supported protocols. It describes the `smb://` protocol, which according to the heading, depends on libsmbclient (from the SAMBA project).

You will have to port libsmbclient to iOS, too, and build FFmpeg with smb support, make sure that iOS allows you to access the network like you'd need to to support SMB, and test things.

Comment: thank you . I  have build the  libsmbclient in  my  project. and  it  works. i can read the file  use  smb  in  my  project.  but  I do  not  know  how make  ffmpeg  support smb when I  build the ffmpeg. Do  you have  some information about this ？